# Sitecore Paas installation failure - AppGallery Deploy Failed: The declared parameter 'Application Path' is not recognized

Tags: jss, azure, paas, arm-template

We are trying to create `Sitecore 9.2` instance in `azure PaaS` using `ARM templates`. The ARM templates worked fine. Now we have modified the ARM templates to install the JSS module with Sitecore while creating a new Sitecore environment. We have ensured we are using the correct `JSS packages (scwdp for CM and CD)` and correct paths for storage location containing these packages. We keep getting the following error -

> AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared parameter 'Application Path' is not recognized

Any idea on how to get this fixed.

We have followed the below links to make changes in ARM templates -

- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/JSS%2012.0.0/xp
- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/blob/master/MODULES.md
- https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-jss-deploy-to-azure-with-arm-templates/